# Why is this Enum class not JAXB-marshalled?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have a Java 8 application using JAXB with MOXy 2.3.2 , and it is working fine with all properties except for an Enum that was introduced recently: `UserProfileExtensionGenderEnum.java`, here is the JAXB object that gets marshalled into an XML.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="root", namespace=ZGXMLHelper.ZWISCHENGAS_NS)
public class UserProfileExtension {
    @XmlElement(name="emailVerifyReminder2Sent", namespace=ZGXMLHelper.ZWISCHENGAS_NS)
    private boolean emailVerifyReminder2Sent = Boolean.FALSE;
    ...
    @XmlElement(name="gender", namespace=ZGXMLHelper.ZWISCHENGAS_NS)
    private UserProfileExtensionGenderEnum gender = UserProfileExtensionGenderEnum.NOTSET; 

}
```

The Enum:

```java
package com.zwischengas.model.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue;

@XmlEnum
public enum UserProfileExtensionGenderEnum {

    @XmlEnumValue("m")
    MALE, 
    @XmlEnumValue("f")
    FEMALE, 
    @XmlEnumValue("notset")
    NOTSET;
    
}
```

All JAXB classes are in the same package, and in that package there is this `package-into.java`:

```java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://zwischengas.com/article/1.0/", 
    xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "z", namespaceURI ="http://zwischengas.com/article/1.0/"),@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "y", namespaceURI ="http://www.wyona.org/yanel/1.0")},  
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.zwischengas.model.jaxb;
```

What is missing in order to have this enum marshalled too?

Answer (score 1):

On Java `enum` generated by [jaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools), I generally have an `@XmlType(name = "myAwesomeEnum")` annotation on the enum with the `@XmlEnum` annotation like the following example :

```java
@XmlType(name = "myAwesomeEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum MyAwesomeEnum {

    FIRST_ENUM("FIRST_ENUM"),
    SECOND_ENUM("SECOND_ENUM"),
    @XmlEnumValue("THIRD3_ENUM")
    THIRD_3_ENUM("THIRD3_ENUM")
}
```

`@XmlEnumValue` is only necessary if name of the enum differs from value (like 3rd enum name)

I'd try to add the `@XmlType(name = "userProfileExtensionGenderEnum")` on your enum to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. The custom enum class is still not marshalled.

Comment: Could you share MRE ?

Comment: The MRE is the one i posted in my question. That's all i have. The strange thing is: I use the same approach for other custom enums, it looks exactly the same way, and they get marshalled without any problems....